# Manually distribute unique string identifiers to mongoDB records with mongoose and checking for duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'm trying to develop a system in MEAN stack which should contain a Card model stored in my DB. This model should have two unique fields, the object ID and the card code which will be an alphanumeric string with 8 characters length. My schema is similar to:

```
var cardSchema = new Schema({
  cod: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  titular: {type: String, required: true, index: true},
  balance: {type: Number, default: 500, min: 0, max: 500, required: true},
  lastCredited: {type: Date, default: Date.now(), required: true}
})
```

And then i was creating my objects like:

cards.js: post create/

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
  let card = new Card()
  card.cod = Card.generateCod()
  card.credit()
  if (/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test(req.body.titular)) {
    card.titular = req.body.titular.toUpperCase()
  }
  else{
    res.status(406).send('Invalid name for titular')
    return
  }
  card.save(function (err, result) {
    if(err) res.status(406).send(err)
    else res.status(200).send(result)
  })
})
```

My static method generateCod was responsible for distributing the random string code to the cards:

```
cardSchema.statics.generateCod = function(){
  let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJ0123456789"
  let cod = ''

  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) cod += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
  return cod
}
```

However, in order to avoid duplicated codes, i was searching for some way to check if the generated code was already in use, and then in the positive case i would generate another one and repeat the process, in the negative case i would simply return the code. The solution i found was sending a query to the DB passing my code as a param and checking the length of the response, should the length be equal to 0, it meant that the code was unique. So far so good, the problem is, since my query happens asynchronously to the code, i can't simply use a while or a for loop to check whether the code is unique and break the loop when it is, cause the break would not work and the loop would keep going forever. I actually tried it like this:

```
while(true){
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) cod += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
  Card.find({cod: cod}, function(err, result) {
      if(result.length === 0) break
  })
}
return cod
```

I also tried:

```
while(true){
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) cod += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
  Card.find({cod: cod}, function(err, result) {
      if(result.length === 0) return cod
  })
}
```

And even:

```
let unique = false
while(!unique){
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) cod += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))
  Card.find({cod: cod}, function(err, result) {
      if(result.length === 0) unique = true
  })
}
return cod
```

But none of those seem to work, the loop always goes forever. I'm relatively new to node backends and i feel like i'm missing something. Does anyone knows how i can break the outer loop from an async callback? Or even an alternative way to avoid duplicates? I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose has built-in support for `Promise`, so you can use `async/await` here:

```
cardSchema.statics.generateCod = async function() {
  let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJ0123456789";
  let cod = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    cod += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }

  let dup = await Card.findOne({cod: cod});

  if (dup) {
      return new Error("Can not generate COD");
  }

  return cod;
}

router.post('/create', async function(req, res) {
  let card = new Card()

  card.cod = await Card.generateCod()

  // ...
})
```

Notice all the `async` and `await` I added.